# Foreign key error 1215

Tags: mysql

I am receiving an

> error code 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint.

When I leave `FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)` 
out of the code it seems to work but when I add it I receive the error.

```
CREATE SCHEMA `my_web_db`;

USE my_web_db;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DOWNLOADS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PRODUCTS;

CREATE  TABLE `my_web_db`.`USERS` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `email_address` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) )
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE  TABLE `my_web_db`.`DOWNLOADS` (
  `download_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `user_id` INT ,
  `download_date` DATETIME NULL ,
  `filename` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`download_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
)
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE  TABLE `my_web_db`.`PRODUCTS` (
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `product_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
)
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: Before modifying or dropping tables, first, try to release the relations.

Comment: Have you tried moving "create table" for products before "Create table" for downloads?

Answer (score 0):

I think your you are using ENGINE=myisam, you should use ENGINE=InnoDB to create foreign key reference.

Added ENGINE type.
Updated SQL:

```
CREATE  TABLE `my_web_db`.`USERS` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `email_address` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE  TABLE `my_web_db`.`PRODUCTS` (
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `product_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE  TABLE `my_web_db`.`DOWNLOADS` (
  `download_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `user_id` INT ,
  `download_date` DATETIME NULL ,
  `filename` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `product_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`download_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: Yes, MyISAM does not support FK, but AFAIK now the default engine is InnoDB.. Or he would get the error also for user_id FK, no?

Comment: And MyISAM just parses and ignores the FKs, it doesn't raise any error.

Comment: The explanation in this answer is wrong but the code is correct. First CREATE the `Users` and the `Products` tables and then the `Downloads` that references the previous 2 tables.